# Color rendering differents in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, colors, color-profile

I want to capture screenshots of a website in different browsers and have assumptions about parts of the website having a specific color (I set it to red beforehand).

However, when I compare the screenshots in Firefox and Chrome looking at them in an image application I can see that indeed, in Chrome the color of the element is #FF0000 whereas in Firefox it is #FC0D1B.

I assume it has something to do with color profiles so I went to Firefox about:config and changed gfx.color_management.mode from 1 to 0. I tried every possible value but there was no difference.

Can't I simply deactivate the color correction or somehow achieve the same result like in Chrome?

It is very important for me that the element is actually #FF0000 because I look for elements with exactly that color with zero threshold.

Here is a very simple jsfiddle where this also happens (only in Firefox).
I just set `background-color:red` https://jsfiddle.net/don1savx/ .

I am using a Macbook Pro 13" 2013. My profile in Preferences -> Displays is set to Color LCD (at least I think this is what it's called in English)

Comment: Please can you provide code so we can attempt to reproduce the issue and if possible the screenshots you refer to?

Comment: Try to disable / enable hardware acceleration in Firefox : Tools > Options > Advanced > General > Browsing: uncheck / check "Use hardware acceleration when available"

Comment: also may you check this link : https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

Comment: I added a jsfiddle

Toggling the hardware acceleration did not help :( and the link you provided suggests to turn off color profiles. That's what I did when I changed gfx.color_management.mode

Comment: what about gfx.color_management.mode = 2?

Comment: 2 is the default option and that's how it was set before

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the issue. Creating an element with background color #FF0000 in firefox screenshot paste in photoshop gave me a color of #FF0000.

There are two ways that Firefox could change your colors. Either a text preference or a theme.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-themes-change-look-of-firefox

I'm on a macbook pro running the latest version of firefox with no add-ons.

Comment: I have no themes installed.
I went to the font/color settings and deactivated the option to overwrite certain colors if there is a high contrast. Now the color is indeed different. However, it is stillt not #FF0000. Now it is #F91628. I also have the latest version with no add-ons.